# Android Expandablelistview with listview as a childview

Tags: android, listview, scrollview, expandablelistview

How to add listview as a child in expandablelistview item click?

Something like the image below

Here when an item is clicked from an expandable list it will expand a listview with fixed height and scrolling. Just like simple expandable list the only difference is I want to open listview with only few data displayed and user can scroll within that list to look for other items.

Unable to post an image due to less reputation.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the [This Expandable List Animation Example in Github](https://github.com/Udinic/SmallExamples/tree/master/ExpandAnimationExample)

YOu can customize this as you wish and use it in your project

Comment: Had already tried something similiar to this ....but problem occurs when childview contains listview with scrollbars ....conflict arises between chil listview scroll and main expandable list scrolling....any more suggestion or idea?

Comment: AFAIK , it is not advisable to have nested scrollable elements. If possible try to restructure your design.

Comment: Tried to add elements with scrollview dynamically as well as in static layout...but it dint worked too..any other good example u can refer?